# what is the difference between IOUtils.toString and EntityUtils.toString. Which one should I use to read response entity

Tags: java, rest, web-services, http

what is the difference between IOUtils.toString and EntityUtils.toString. Which one from below should be used to read response entity and why?

```
1) CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            data=  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

OR

```
2)  CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
     data = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(),
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: One consumes an HttpEntity, the other consumes a Stream. Look at the extra steps you need for #2 compared to #1 to get everything to work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `EntityUtils`, it works with entity object directly. In your second example, `response.getEntity().getContent()` returns InputStream, which must be closed (your example code doesn't do that). `EntityUtils` handles this on its own. `EntityUtils` also reads encoding of the content from entity headers, you don't need to pass UTF_8 constant, which may be wrong, if content is actually encoded using different encoding.